# Stripe Webhook Cases not being handled

Tags: node.js, heroku, stripe-payments

```
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async (request, response) => {
const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

let event;

try {
  event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
}
catch (err) {
  response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
}

// Handle the event
switch (event.type) {
  case 'payment_intent.succeeded':

  case 'customer.subscription.created':

  case 'payment_method.attached':

  case 'customer.subscription.updated':
    console.log('this should run');
  default:
    console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
}

// Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
response.json({received: true});
```

});

Server Logs: 2021-01-04T08:32:39.522281+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled event type customer.subscription.updated

This is live currently, why doesn't the customer.subscription.updated run and only the default: run and how do I fix this? My keys are correct (Using secret key, and endpoint key for right webhook). I shouldn't be getting unhandled event type for an event that is handled.

Comment: Maybe you're missing `break` statements? So both the matched case and the default are running.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break